Non-column output of `ls` piped to `sed`
As far as I know, command sed precesses its input line by line. Thus, the following command successfully outputs only the directories in the current directory:
$ ls -p -1 | sed -n '/\/$/p'

Here option -1 to ls makes its output appear in a column, so sed can process it line by line. However, if I remove option -1 this command still works. Why? Without option -1 the output of ls is not a set of separated lines.
EDIT
I posted the question here in the Unix & Linux forum, just to get it also closed soon after because it's a duplicate. Anyway, I got the answer reading the question referenced by duplicate highlight there. Thanks.

ls detects that its stdout is not connected to a terminal and produces output reusable by other utilities. This kind of questions are better suited at [unix.se].

To actually list directories directly with ls, try ls -d */; but for programmatic use, generally don't use ls in scripts.

Regarding your edit, that's why questions get closed as duplicates: to redirect you to an existing question that already answers yours. It doesn't mean go post the same question on a different site.

See at Unix & Linux: is piped ls the same as ls -1?

Binaries can use the isatty library function to test if their file descriptors are associated with a terminal.
Many tools do this and change their output accordingly, e.g. most tools will output ANSI color codes when printing to the terminal, but only plain text when redirecting to a file or piping to another process. ls will also disable colored output and switches to 1 file per line mode.
You can easily verify by looking at the source code of ls from coreutils:
  format = (0 <= format_opt ? format_opt
            : ls_mode == LS_LS ? (stdout_isatty ()
                                  ? many_per_line : one_per_line)
            : ls_mode == LS_MULTI_COL ? many_per_line
            : /* ls_mode == LS_LONG_FORMAT */ long_format);

Related: What is isatty() in C for?
